# Bizarrely unable to connect to a domain from within server

Tags: networking, server, dns

I'm unable to connect to `github.com` IF and only if I attempt to do so from within my LAN server (let's call its FQDN `server.com`).  If I `ssh server.com` and then attempt, say, `curl github.com`, a "no route to host" type error is produced:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to github.com port 80: No route to host
```

The server in question has active DNS (bind9), DHCP, HTTP/s and SSH services and, in particular, is the DNS resolver for all machines on the LAN.  Please see bottom of post for some hopefully useful information.

I can connect to GitHub just fine on *any* of my other local machines, however.

How do I diagnose and fix this?

---

```
$ systemd-resolve github.com
github.com: 192.30.253.113
            192.30.253.112

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 48.2ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no

$ host -v github.com
Trying "github.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47061
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;github.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
github.com.     8   IN  A   192.30.253.113
github.com.     8   IN  A   192.30.253.112

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           513652  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 133062  IN  AAAA    2001:500:a8::e
G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 483477  IN  AAAA    2001:500:12::d0d

Received 347 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 0 ms
Trying "github.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37084
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;github.com.            IN  AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
github.com.     660 IN  SOA ns-1707.awsdns-21.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

Received 112 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 0 ms
Trying "github.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39053
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;github.com.            IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
github.com.     844 IN  MX  1 aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com.     844 IN  MX  10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com.     844 IN  MX  5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com.     844 IN  MX  5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
github.com.     844 IN  MX  10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           513652  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           513652  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 133062  IN  AAAA    2001:500:a8::e
G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 483477  IN  AAAA    2001:500:12::d0d

Received 430 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 0 ms

$ sudo traceroute -ITU github.com
traceroute to github.com (192.30.253.112), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  server.com (192.168.0.2)  2998.275 ms !H  2998.252 ms !H  2998.238 ms !H
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected this was somehow related to the fact that I was using the `192.168.0.0/16` subnet in my LAN and indeed it turned out to be the case.  To understand what the problem was and eventually solve it, I started by querying the server's routing, which revealed a strange netmask:

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp5s0 onlink                                                                                                                  
192.0.0.0/8 dev enp5s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.2
```

Looking in `/etc/network/interfaces` revealed the culprit:

```
iface enp5s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.0.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

I cannot remember anymore if back when I set-up the server the Ubuntu Server installation prompted me for details about the network or whether it silently made the above assumptions.  I actually believe it is configured out of the box to expect a `10.0.0.0/8` subnet and I must have mistakenly changed it to `192.168.*.*` but forgot about the netmask.

In any case, I then corrected the netmask above to `255.255.0.0` and executed `systemctl restart networking`.  Running `ip route show` showed the new netmask in effect but *also* the old one, strangely.  I had to explicitly delete the old route with `ip route delete 192.0.0.0/8 dev enp5s0` and *then* it all worked.

---

**EDIT:** the answer to the first part of my question (how to diagnose) was to look at the machine's routing, which, if you're having similar network connectivity problems to mine, might be a good place to look at first.